# Azure Graph api user creation - property values specified are invalid

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a problem with Azure AD Graph API integration where we try to create user to existing Active directory. Used azure documentation to work on this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#UpdateUser)

For some reason the example dataset is not working, but I'm receiving:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "One or more property values specified are invalid."
        },
        "values": null
    }
}
```

The dataset I'm passing is

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "Test User",
    "mailNickname": "TestUser",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "Test1234",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
    },
    "userPrincipalName": "Test@_MY_DOMAIN_.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

`_MY_DOMAIN_` is one of the domains defined in the Active directory's domains.

If I try e.g. removing any of the required fields, I'm receiving error which defines the missing property.

Listing and updating users is working just fine, there is some weird issue with adding.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've submitted some changes to your post to help improve the formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you check the password requirements? Min. 8 chars, special characters or something else?

Comment: Didn't help. Tried with different combination and special characters / character lengths. I guess it might be related to AD configurations, but pretty hard to figure it out as the application permissions should be more than enough, and all updates / listings etc works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we will get this issue when we haven't set the Url in the correct format. I tested your dataset on my side, it worked fine. Please double check the url.

Here is the capture of my test request:
[image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Looks like in your example you are doing the update? It is working fine also for us with existing users in our active directory. The problem is adding the user, which is (based on the documentation) Post request to the /_tenant_id_/users?api-version=1.6

Comment: Please try to use `Post` to `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version`, with your dataset. And refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CreateUser for more. Your previous link referred to the update user functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably problem was related to Azure AD permissions. Somehow started suddenly working.

One thing figured out is that the error message above will also come e.g. if you have property key mistyped. Sometimes response describes the missing property, but not always.

Thanks everyone for your time..